# How to set SOAP version using HttpWebRequest

Tags: vb.net, soap, httpwebrequest

I'm getting "(415) Unsupported Media Type" when trying to send the following WSDL:

```
Dim xml1 As String = String.Empty
xml1 = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" "
xml1 += "xmlns:ser=""http://client_server.com/"">"
xml1 += "<soapenv:Header/>"
xml1 += "<soapenv:Body>"
xml1 += "XML_CONTENT"
xml1 += "</soapenv:Body>"
xml1 += "</soapenv:Envelope>"
'----------------------------
Dim a As New System.Text.ASCIIEncoding()
Dim buffer As Byte() = a.GetBytes(xml1)
Dim request As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("http://server.com?wsdl"), HttpWebRequest)
request.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = False
request.KeepAlive = False
request.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "")
request.Method = "POST"
request.ContentType = "application/soap+xml; charset=""UTF-8"""
request.Accept = "text/xml"
Dim stm As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
stm.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
stm.Close()
Dim resp As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
stm = resp.GetResponseStream()
```

From what I understand, the reason for the exception is because the server is using a different SOAP version ("1.1") than the one on my request ("1.2", I guess).
How do I set the SOAP version?
Or is there another way to solve this "Unsupported Media Type" error?

Answer (score 0):

It worked by removing the line where I fill the "ContentType" property ("request.ContentType = "application/soap+xml; charset=UTF-8"")